# Save lines for each file in directory

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to get all of the files from a certain directory, and save each of the lines.

```
for /r %%i in (C:\SECMD\Mods\modHandler\ModDir\*.txt) do (
set "file=%%i"
(
echo %%i
set /p Line_1=
set /p Line_2=
echo %Line_1%
) <C:\SECMD\Mods\modHandler\ModDir\%file%
)

pause
```

But the for command isn't detecting any files, even though I have 2 in the directory. Here's an example of a text file:

```
C:\SECMD\Mods\modHandler\modHandler.bat
modHandler.bat
```

I'm aware that the variable is overwritten, I can figure that out after this gets fixed.

Comment: Post a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), e.g. `for ... do ( echo %%i )`.

Comment: Maybe you should read the help file for the `FOR` command with the `/R` option. `FOR /R [[drive:]path] %variable IN (set) DO.....`  You are also inside a code block so you need to use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). If you want to read the contents of a file then use a `FOR /F`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir "%CD%" /b /A:-D')  do (
echo %%A
)
```